# My background will not show through glass object in blender, glass object is white/grey

Tags: blender

I have an object that is glass, in the view port shader area it looks ok, but in the rendered viewport it is white/grey and not showing the green background through the glass, I have watched so many tutorials and none have this issue, what am i doing wrong?

[Monkey head in the shader viewport (looks ok)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfGQO.png)

[Monkey head in the render viewport (somethings wrong)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmL7L.png)

[Shader settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jO6S.png)

[Render settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzBAU.png)

Comment: Could you re-upload/edit your shader settings screenshot? The resolution isn't sufficient to read it.

Comment: ok i have updated the picture